# Access file in UWP using statically built non-UWP lib

Tags: uwp

In my UWP, I link a statically built lib, which is built on Win32.
I need to use this lib to access file, more specifically using this lib to do deserialization and I am not sure if I can use it in UWP.
If not, do I need to rewrite deserialization using UWP?

Thanks.

YL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not sure if I can use it in UWP. If not, do I need to rewrite deserialization using UWP?

It dependents on which APIs that you've used in your win32 library. Not all win32 APIs are available in UWP. You could check [Win32 and COM APIs for UWP apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-and-com-for-uwp-apps) for more details.

> In the case of a static library, you can link to your library simply by adding the library (.lib file) to your linker input, just as you would in a classic Win32 application. For libraries where only a binary is available, this is the only option. A static library is linked into your app's executable, but a Win32 DLL that you consume in a UWP app must be packaged into the app by including it in the project and marking it as Content. To load a Win32 DLL in a Universal Windows Platform app, you also have to call [LoadPackagedLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/hh447159.aspx) instead of LoadLibrary or LoadLibraryEx.

Please read [How to: Use Existing C++ Code in a Universal Windows Platform App](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt186162.aspx) for more reference.